# How to highlight string inside <code/> tag in react? dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.body}} />
```

**Hi mates**

I am using the above to display the html in string format. This string is returned from stackexchange api. And I want to highlight the Text inside the code block. the string will look like this

```
<p>I'm doing the same as shown in the documentation <a href=\"https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt\" rel=\"nofollow noreferrer\">here</a>.\nI want to Inject the ViewModel into a Composable function (Screen), but I get this error:</p>\n<blockquote>\n<p>Cannot create an instance of class\ncom.example.blotube.ui.later.LaterViewModel</p>\n</blockquote>\n<p><strong>My ViewModel:</strong></p>\n<pre><code>@HiltViewModel\nclass LaterViewModel @Inject constructor(\n    private val database: Database\n):ViewModel() {\n\n    val watchLater=database.videos().getAll()\n\n}\n</code></pre>\n<p><strong>My Composable Function (Screen):</strong></p>\n<pre><code>@Composable\nfun WatchLater(vm: LaterViewModel = viewModel()){\n\n\n    val videos=vm.watchLater.observeAsState()\n    val context= LocalContext.current\n    \n\n}\n</code></pre>\n"
```

I want to display this or I want to display the stackoverflow web in my website i have tried it using iframe. But it doesn't help me it just said the web refused to connect. Both answers or solutions are accpeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use prism.js library to achieve this.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/themes/prism.min.css" />


</head>

<body>
    <pre>
        <code class="language-javascript">
                <p>I'm doing the same as shown in the documentation <a href="https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt" rel="nofollow noreferrer">here</a>.
                I want to Inject the ViewModel into a Composable function (Screen), but I get this error:</p>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Cannot create an instance of classcom.example.blotube.ui.later.LaterViewModel</p>
            </blockquote>
            <p><strong>My ViewModel:</strong></p>
            <pre>
                <code class="language-javascript">
                    @HiltViewModelclass LaterViewModel @Inject constructor(private val database: Database):ViewModel() {
                    val watchLater=database.videos().getAll()}
                </code>
            </pre>
            <p><strong>My Composable Function (Screen):</strong></p>
            <pre>
                <code class="language-javascript">
                    @Composablefun WatchLater(vm: LaterViewModel = viewModel())
                    {val videos=vm.watchLater.observeAsState()val context= LocalContext.current}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </code>
    </pre>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.5.0/prism.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```